# GTM Cross-Domain Tracking for new AdWords conversion

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, safari, cross-domain, google-ads-api

You may all know that Apple introduced 3rd party cookie deletion after 24 hours into Safari 11 on Mobile and Desktop called Intelligent Tracking Prevention ITP.

This forced Google to change their AdWords pixel to use a 1st party instead of a 3rd party cookie.

I'm not sure what to do in the following scenario:

Landing page is domain1.com with a link to domain2.com/register where users can fill out a form and convert and it will load domain2.com/thankyou

In the past I would just set up GTM like this:

**Tag: AdWords Remarketing**

```
 Trigger: All Pages
```

**Tag: AdWords Conversion**

```
 Trigger: Page View, where url=domain2.com/thankyou
```

**Tag: Universal Analytics**

```
 Set field: autoLinker=true

 Add cross-domains: domain2.com

 Trigger: All Pages
```

This worked perfectly because Analytics uses a 1st party cookie, so we make sure the cross-domain tracking for Analytics works. For AdWords we didn't need to worry, as it used a 3rd party cookie that will perfectly work across domains.

**Question**

Since AdWords switched to a 1st party cookie, they nag us in GTM to add a Conversion Linker without much settings to set. I don't see how this works with a 1st party cookie, without a cross-domain linker for AdWords.

Any ideas if for AdWords everything just works without any sort of cross-domain linker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one and a half years later this gets finally fixed by google. GTM allows for link and form decoration, to transfer it's 1st party cookie to the second domain:

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7549390?linkId=58009916

"Enable linking across domains"